# Error al reiniciar apache

Tags: apache, gitlab, centos7

Tengo un servidor centos 7 con do dominios uno para gitlab y un segundo que uso con apache.
Todo funciona correctamente hasta que habilito https para ambos dominios.
A partir de este momento, apache no se inicia si tengo habilitado el servidor gitlab.

-Obtengo lo siguiente al ejecutar  journalctl -xe:

```
-- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up.
sep 24 13:41:04 centOS httpd[9397]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
sep 24 13:41:04 centOS httpd[9397]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
sep 24 13:41:04 centOS httpd[9397]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
sep 24 13:41:04 centOS httpd[9397]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
sep 24 13:41:04 centOS systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
sep 24 13:41:04 centOS kill[9400]: kill: cannot find process ""
sep 24 13:41:04 centOS systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
sep 24 13:41:04 centOS systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit httpd.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
sep 24 13:41:04 centOS systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
sep 24 13:41:04 centOS systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
sep 24 13:41:04 centOS polkitd[488]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:9391:222460 (system bus name :1.101, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authentica
```

Comment: ¿En qué puertos tienes gitlab? Un proceso no puede ponerse a escuchar en un puerto (*bind*) si ya hay alguien escuchando en dicho puerto. El log te dice que apache no puede hacer el *bind* al puerto 80.

Comment: Gitlab está corriendo en el puerto 3737.

Comment: Yo haría un `netstat -punt` (con permisos de *root*) para ver si el puerto 80 está levantado y qué proceso lo ha levantado.

Comment: E echo netstat -punt como root y no veo ningún proceso que este usando el puerto 80. :(

Comment: Solucionado había una entrada Listen duplicada en el archivo httpd.conf